# Ajax.BeginForm to specify "GET" type posting

Tags: c#, html, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5

My view is as below:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "DisplayPatients" }))
{
    <input type="search" name="searchTerm" />
    <input type="submit" value="Do Search" />
}
```

Whenever I try to compile and I view the source of the html page that I get, I see,

```
<form action="/" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="Get" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#DisplayPatients" id="form0" 
   method="post">
```

But, in my Ajax.BeginForm, I specify the `HttpMethod = Get`. Inspite being this, I get the `method = "post"` in the output html page.

Any ideas why ? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I even checked my page source by `view-source` in my browser. This shows:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<form action="/" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="Get" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#DisplayPatients" id="form0" method="post">    <input type="search" name="searchTerm" />
```

(Notice that the script (jquery-unobstrusive) actually is there)

Comment: Is it actualy making a post or a get request.  The actual action of the form probably doesn't matter with ajax calls, it probably just uses the data-ajax-method attribute.

Comment: @BenRobinson: I actually want a `get` request to be made. Thats why I specify `HttpMethod = "Get"` in my `Ajax.BeginForm`.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed., he's asking you **what request is *actually* being made**? Consider the fact that an AJAX call is done in JavaScript and so it can do *any kind of method* it wants.

Comment: @neoistheone: makes sense, so irrespective of `method` action in a form, the request type is always deduced from `data-ajax-method`. If that's a `get` request, then its always a `get` request.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed., that's correct because the JavaScript determines how it's actually requested - an in this case it uses that attribute to make that determination.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But, in my Ajax.BeginForm, I specify the HttpMethod = Get. Inspite
>   being this, I get the method = "post" in the output html page.

The `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script ignores the `method` attribute and uses `data-ajax-method` (if present). So the actual request will be GET. Look at the Network tab of your Google Chrome developer console to see.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to say, and so thanks for confirming this for me Darin!

Comment: @Darin: Thanks for clarifying that. But, even then, at execution, the control goes to the action-method with `[HttpPost]` . When I click my `submit` button, it does not go to the action-method with `[HttpGet]` action filter.

Comment: That's probably because you forgot to include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script to your page and the Ajax.BeginForm acts as a simple Html.BeginForm -> there's no script to interpret those data-* attributes and the browser simply submits the form.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: But, i see that i have included that Darin. Kindly see my edit.

Comment: Do you see the AJAX request being sent in your Google Chrome Developer console? Look at the Network tab. That's where you should see it. If you don't see it, you either didn't include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script, or you included it in the wrong place or you have some other javascript error in your page which is preventing its execution.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Sorry for being naive, you could please tell me how to do that ?

Comment: Sure, you launch the Google Chrome webbrowser, press F12 to open the developer toolbar and navigate to your website. Then look at the Network tab of the developer toolbar. That's where you will see the requests being sent to the server. Now submit the form and see if an AJAX request is being made or a normal POST request.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38791/discussion-between-now-he-who-must-not-be-named-and-darin-dimitrov)

Comment: Do you have `jquery.js` included? What you have shown in your updated question is the 3 javascript inclusions but they won't work if you do not have jquery.js included **BEFORE** them. Also look at the console tab of your developer toolbar for potential javascript errors.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Thanks dude. It worked like charm. So, actually i understand now, that these inclusions must have `jquery.js` above them.

Comment: Yes, they are simple jquery plugins.

Answer (score 3):

Even though including the jQuery file works, I still feel it's incorrect to have POST in there. You can "override" it by specifying it in the html attributes:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "results" }, new { @id = "search", @role = "search", @method="get" }))
```

You may be able to set it so null or blank, too, using this hack. Just FYI.