# Ajax,BeginForm Post 404 not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajaxform

I have next method in controller:

```
public ViewResult List(string category, string price, string SelectedValue, int page = 1)
{
    ViewBag.CurrentSort = SelectedValue;

    var Furnitures = repository.Furnitures
                .Where(p => category == null || p.Category.Name == category)
                .ToList();

    if(SelectedValue != null)
    {
        if (SelectedValue.Equals("OrderByDescending"))
        {
            Furnitures = Furnitures.OrderByDescending(z => z.Price).ToList();
        }

    }

    Furnitures = Furnitures.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
                           .Take(pageSize).ToList();

    ListViewModel model = new ListViewModel
    {
        Furnitures = Furnitures,
        InfoPages = new InfoPage
        {
            CurrentPage = page,
            ItemsPerPage = pageSize,
            TotalItems = category == null ? repository.Furnitures.Count() :
                    repository.Furnitures.Where(furniture => furniture.Category.Name == category).Count()
        },
        CurrentCategory = category,
        Fields = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Order By Descending", Value = "OrderByDescending" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Order By Ascending", Value = "OrderByAscending" },
        }
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

I try to order my list of products with dropdownlist filter using Ajax. This is my code from View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("List", "Furniture", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "content" , Confirm = "Выполнить AJAX-запрос?" , InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue,
                     new SelectList(Model.Fields, "Value", "Text", Model.SelectedValue), "-- Select Product--")
    <input type="submit" value="Display" />

}
```

My problem is when I submit form , I get an error in Console:

```
jquery-3.1.1.js:9536 POST http://localhost:61741/ 404 (Not Found)
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error . I downloaded Nuget Package jquery.unobtrusive-ajax and included script in my View but still get error. Maybe something wrong with parameters , maybe I should pass them to controller? Thanks!

Comment: Have you marked that method with `[HttpPost]`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hi , no , this method just Get data from database , also I implemented sorting and paging

Comment: `Ajax.BeginForm()` makes a POST by default! - you need to specify `FormMethod.Get`

Comment: And as a sid note, its just `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, Model.Fields)` - the `new SelectList()` code is pointless extra overhead - it just creates another identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the first one)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I tried to add HttpMethod = "Get" to my Ajax.BeginForm() , but method="post" doesn't change. Here is generated html <form action="/" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-confirm="Выполнить AJAX-запрос?" data-ajax-method="Get" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#content" id="form0" method="post">

Comment: @StephenMuecke okay when I add Get  , I get new error: GET http://localhost:61741 / ?SelectedValue=OrderByDescending&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest&_=1511778187227 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Do you have `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` correctly loaded in your view?

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes  https://imgur.com/YFoYPK3

Comment: @StephenMuecke maybe I should pass parameters in this form , such as    Html.TextBox("category", (string)ViewBag.Category, new { class = "hidden" }) but I try this , and now i get GET http: //localhost:61741/?SelectedValue=OrderByDescending&category=%D0%9B%D1%96%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest&_=1511880695607 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Add [HttpPost] on the top of your controller method.
2. Try to send parameters by putting it inside a class.
3. Try with $.ajax(function(){}); Check if this works or not.If this works then you must be missing the point 1. Point 3 is another alternative way in which you can implement the same.
4. Check if you have any authorization set on controller/method and this method is not accessible from where you are assessing it(might be).

Comment: hi , If i put HttpPost   ,then my page wil be not loading  , I get 404 that page not found , I understand why but I don't know what to write in separate HttpPost method , because I just get data from database

Comment: Are you trying to implement some sort of a filter with only one method in controller? If you do not have 2 methods for action then I guess you are trying to implement some sort of filter. Try adding FormMethod.Get in Ajax.BeginForm...I think that should work...only the values will go on the URL as a query string.

Comment: I implemented only one method where I sort, It's a List , (code in my question)  , I just don't understand , what's wrong, now I get new error , when choose to Get in Ajax.BeginForm:  GET http://localhost:61741 /?SelectedValue=OrderByDescending&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest&_=1511778187227 404 (Not Found)

Comment: In AjaxOptions try HttpMethod= Get

Comment: I have added it , after this  I get  localhost:61741 /?SelectedValue=OrderByDescending&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRe‌​quest&_=151177818722‌​7 404 (Not Found)

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248043/ajax-beginform-to-specify-get-type-posting.. it will help I guess..